# Error message in AVR studio4

Tags: microcontroller, avr-studio4

I have recently purchased an AVR USB programmer from robokits.co.in, was trying to program atmeg8 using AVR studio4 and I get the following when I click on the program options:

> a problem occurred when executing the command. make sure u are using
>   the correct programming method. current mode is ISP  verify that the
>   device is placed in the correct socket, and that the ISP cable is
>   connected properly.check that the programming frequency specified in
>   the main page is well below 1/4th of the clock frequency of the
>   device.

I have tried all that I could think of, I have checked the connections  and the freq is below 1/4th of the device.

But that doesn't solve this problem.

I have made the circuit for blinking LEDs program.

[See the image for details](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_Fa6w_-W-IXs/SQV9DQ54-1I/AAAAAAAAAIE/1XI3HX5ESRk/s1600-h/a.jpg)

Comment: I assume you're referring to this:
http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=12&products_id=54

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the jumpers on the programming board that you are using (if you are) are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is hardly the venue to trouble shoot different hardware issues.

So if you think there is an issue with the programmer, contact www.robokits.com.
I would start with contacting robokits.

Since you can't even enter the programming mode, you can ignore your source code.
You should be able to verify fuses/lock bits w/o programming any code into the Mega8.

To give you a head start before you contact robokits:

1.  Verify the programmer is properly installed on your computer following robokits instructions.

2.  Verify the +5Vdc on Pins 20 & 7 of the Mega8

3.  Verify Pins 22 & 8 are grounded properly.

4.  Verify that Pin 1 is pulled up to +5Vdc (when the programmer is not connected)

Pin 1 should be pulled down by the programmer when it attempts to connect to the Mega8

5.  Double check all the connections between the programmer to your target.  Since the programmer is a 10 pin IDC and the test circuit has an in-line style connector you must have an IDC cable that has been broken out, stripped and connected to the test circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Target "fresh"?  i.e. Never been programmed?  Regardless: have you tried more than one?
Do you have any power being applied to the ISP header (target) prior to connecting the programmer?

You may also want to verify there are no shorts on your Target pulling the ISP Supply down, see the pinout link below.

If your jumper settings are USB-HID and Slow SCK == open && ISP Supply == short then you shouldn't supply and power to the ISP connection from the target.

If you are not supplying and voltage to the ISP header, maybe you should try that.  Remove the ISP Supply jumper and apply 5V from your target application's supply to the ISP interface:
[AVR ISP Pinout](http://www.hardwarebook.info/AVR_ISP)

Pin 2 on the ISP interface should be +5Vdc in reference to Pin 10 (gnd)

Answer (score 0):

When I got a similar message while programming other Atmel integrated circuits I enabled the "Use external reset" setting that exists in the GUI of AVR Studio 4 (was removed in 5 and returned in Atmel Studio 6).

I am not sure if that option exists or does anything with your programmer since I have never used it.